# Is a question trying to remember the name of a place I've been to during a trip on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

In 2012 during an Euro-trip I spent some days in Vienna (Austria's capital). During that trip I got a recommendation for a restaurant from a local citizen. I really liked the restaurant and memorized it's name for future usage.

Fast forward to December 2019, I have a couple of friends in Vienna and I suggested this same restaurant to them, but to my disappointment I can't find anything about it. Probably my memory is playing me a trick, but I have a few things about this restaurant that I know for sure. I know more or less it's name, the approximate location and a date when it was open.

**QUESTION:** Is a question specifying what I know about this restaurant and asking if someone knows how's it called, on-topic for Travel SE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say that **yes**, it is on topic.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Just [asked it](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/150438/looking-for-a-restaurant-in-vienna-with-a-name-similar-to-an-die-2-linsen-that)